# Is this the correct way to repeat a game loop?

Tags: python

Im trying to make a space invadors game on pygame. Once the player dies, i want to check if the retry button has been clicked. If it has, i want the game to start playing again. This is the code i currently have for when the game ends however, when i click the retry button the game doesnt play. How do i repeat my main game while loop?

```
for i in range(num_of_enemies):
    #Game over
    if enemyY[i] > 390:
        for j in range(num_of_enemies):
            enemyY[j] = 2000
            playerY = 2000
            laserX = 2000
            game_over_text(0, 0)
            if retry_button.draw():
                running = True
```

Comment: Not really.  You should have a function that sets up your "initial condition".  When the last player dies, you'll display a "game over" message, and then wait for a click on the "retry" button.  The "retry" button handler will call your "initial conditions" function again.  Usually, in an event-driven system, you won't have infinite loops like that.

Comment: you can break this into separate functions. Have one function to actually play the game, that exits when player wins(return 1) or game over (return 0).  Then you can have another function that checks for the retry button using the exact `if` condition you have. If you detect it being clicked, you again call your play_game() function

Answer (score 0):

I would need more of your code to know for sure, but if this function is inside of your main game loop, your main loop would probably look like `while running == True:` ? There is a few things that could be happening to cause your came to not run if this is the case, syntax error (example: `while running = True:` would run but wouldnt check if running is equal to true), you are somehow setting running to false somewhere else, or it is not recognizing your button click so `if retry_button.draw():` is passed over.